# How to SendDataToServer?

Tags: android, json, server

Condition: I've a button. When user click the button (example ADD NEW NAME button) so the data will send to server.

I've question: How to add new data to server?

What should I put into onResponse and onFailure based on this code:

```
 private void sendDataToServer() {
    APIClient client = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIClient.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> result = client.addNewName(etName.getText().toString(),
            etEnglish.getText().toString(),
            etGender.getText().toString());

    result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        }

    );}
```

*et - Edit Text

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend to you to check **Firebase API** I've been using this library, and it makes easier to work with JSON https://www.firebase.com/

Comment: you have already sent data to server, `onResponse()` can simply check some values in response if ur api provides that, ex, `result_code` and you can show a message or toast (operation completed) or any other UI/storage... changes needed based on that action, same goes for `onFailure()` this function is called when the request fails, -roughly- http-response code was not 200, or request was not sent in first place)

Comment: can you show me some sample code (full) ? I'm using retrofit and json